# JSON help - TypeError: Object of type generator is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, typeerror, generator

I'm trying to save the JSON I've pulled from an API into a file path. I've written a code below that prints the type of the JSON when pulled from the API, another that prints the type when it's been filtered by my FilterData Class, and another that prints its type when put into a list. It worked yesterday but now is throwing me an error.

What am I doing wrong with the FilterData class and FilterData.ProcessData method that is making me keep getting this error :

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'generator'>
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "games_per_day.py", line 151, in <module>
    main()
  File "games_per_day.py", line 103, in main
    saved_data.to_file(
  File "games_per_day.py", line 83, in to_file
    json.dump(self.file, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type generator is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my code

```
class FilterData:
    def __init__(self, operations):
        self.operations = operations

    @staticmethod
    def filter_operations(operation, response):
        for item in operation.get("filter"):
            # print(item)
            data = response
            for i in item.get("path").split("."):
                data = data[i]
            for x in data:
                if x.get(item.get("field")) == item.get("value"):
                    yield x

    def process_data(self, file_response):
        for key in self.operations.keys():
            if key == "filter":
                yield self.filter_operations(key, file_response)


class SaveData:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def to_file(self, output_path):
        with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(self.file, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


def main():
    call = NBARapidApi(API_KEY)
    api_data = call.get_games_list("2021-10-04")
    print(type(api_data))
    filter_list = {
        "filter": [
            {
                "path": "api.games",
                "field": "league",
                "value": "standard"
            }
        ]
    }
    data_filter = FilterData(filter_list)
    print(type(data_filter.process_data(api_data)))
    print(type(list(data_filter.process_data(api_data))))
    saved_data = SaveData(list(data_filter.process_data(api_data)))
    saved_data.to_file(FILE_PATH)
```

any help would be much appreciated